# levels of indirection in c

Tags: c, pointers

Dear wise stackexchangers, I've put myself upto 8 hours of continuous thinking but can't still figure out the correct interpretation of the following code:

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char** pWords = calloc(10, sizeof(char*));


    *(pWords + 1) = malloc(10);

    strcpy_s(*(pWords + 1), 10, "Test sent\0");

    printf("The string is: %s", *(pWords + 1));

    return 0;

}
```

The output from this is:

```
The string is: Test sent
```

I have interpreted the memory allocation as:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+......
|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|......
+-------+-------+-------+-------+......
^       ^
|       |
|       |
pointer(let) <-------malloc(10)
|
|
pWords  <------calloc(10, sizeof(char*))
```

I basically am not understanding the part involving the levels of indirection and the pointers:

first of all pWords is declared as a pointer to a pointer. (I have supposed it to be `pointer` for instance. Then just using one " * " symbol would refer to this `pointer`, right? Then what would pWord point to when it was initialized to : `calloc(10, sizeof(char*))`?
And why would `*(pWords + 1)` be used to access the contents of the pointer that was declared with two levels of indirection `**`? Shouldn't it be             `**(pWords + 1)`?

Comment: Two things: First of all string literals are terminated, you don't need to explicitly add the terminator. Secondly, an expression like `*(pWords + 1)` is equal to `pWords[1]`. Little less to write, and usually more understandable.

Comment: First they create an array of pointer on char (i.e "string"). Then at position 1 (pWords[1]) they create another array of char (string) of length 10. Which in they put the string "Test sent". Then, they simply print the value of this pointer which is "Test sent".

Comment: We normally write `*(pWords + 1)` in the simpler form `pWords[1]`.

Comment: Also, about the double dereferencing. If `pWords` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`, then using single dereference (i.e. `*pWords`) is a pointer to `char`. Dereferencing that in turn (i.e. `**pWords`) must then be a single `char`. Again, using array indexing syntax makes it much more simple: `*pWords` is equal to `pWords[0]`, and `**pWords` is equal to `pWords[0][0]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , but there are char** pWords

Comment: It is exactly what it says: A pointer to a pointer to `char`. Generally you can think of a pointer as an array, so you have an array of pointers to `char`. Or an array of arrays of `char`, or an array of strings.

Answer (score 5):

It's easy to get in a confused state when dealing with strings in C.  Strings aren't really first-class citizens in C, so we have a convention of referring to them using a **pointer to the first character**.  The end of the string is, as you know, indicated by a NUL character.

You allocate memory:

```
char** pWords = calloc(10, sizeof(char*));
```

Here, you've created an array of 10 pointers to pointer-to-char (which you will be using to address 10 strings).  Next, you point the second of those 10 pointers to point to some new memory:

```
*(pWords + 1) = malloc(10);
pWords[1] = malloc(10);  /* this is exactly equivalent, and more idiomatic */
```

Now, you pass that second pointer as the target parameter to `strcpy_s()`.  It will write to the pointed-to `char`, and subsequent ones, finishing with the NUL character to mark the end of the string:

```
strcpy_s(pWords[1], 10, "Test sent");
```

Then you print the string; to do this you pass the same pointer (the second of the ten pointers you allocated) to `printf()`.

```
printf("The string is: %s\n", pWords[1]);
```

---

A couple of side notes:

- You didn't check the return values of any of the functions you called to see if they reported errors.  I'll assume that's just to keep your question short, but remember that this kind of error checking is *very important* in C - if you don't check, your program will most likely fail in a mysterious and baffling manner.
- You should normally `free()` the memory allocated by `malloc()` or `calloc()`.  At the end of your program, it's normally safe to just abandon it, but you may still find it helpful when debugging to at least have the option to clean up.  This can help you when you're looking for actual memory leaks elsewhere in your code.
- Using `calloc()` to reserve memory for pointers does not guarantee that the pointers will be null pointers.  It's tricky and confusing, because there's magic in C that converts a `0` written in your code to the right kind of null pointer when you need it, even if your target platform doesn't actually represent null pointers as all zero bits.
- If you give a function like `strcpy` a string literal with an embedded `\0`, it will treat that NUL as the end of the string.  You can demonstrate this:

  ```
  printf("%s\n", "foo\0bar");
  ```

  Printing will stop after "foo", and "bar" will not be used.
- `char **pointer` isn't exactly the same as `char *pointer[number]`. The former is a pointer to a pointer to a `char` (and it *can* point into an array), while the latter *is* an array of `char*`.  Again, it gets confusing, because we tend to refer to memory from `malloc()` and friends as "array" if we intend to use it as one (with array indexing or other pointer arithmetic).

Comment: ,two confusions:  is char** ptr another way of declaring an array of pointers : char *pointer[number]

Comment: and isn't *(pWords + i) or pWord[i] a pointer? why isn't it deferenced with two levels: **(pWords + i) or *pWord[i] to access the value stored in it? Shouldn't it had printed it's address instead, since it has two levels of indirection?

Comment: @BumbleBee No. `char** ptr != char *pointer[number]`. The former is a pointer to a pointer to a `char` while the latter is an array of `char*`s, i.e, pointer to `char`s

Comment: The definition of `strncpy` and `printf("%s")` say that they accept a pointer (specifically a `char*`), and that's what we're giving them.  The type of `pWord[i]` is `char*`.  The type of `*(pWord[1])` is `char`, and its value (after the copy) is `'T'`.  Does that help?

Comment: @BumbleBee Yes. `pWord[i]` and `*(pWord + i)` (which are the same thing) are pointers. Double dereference `**` wasn't used because the `%s` in `printf` doesn't want the first character of the first string, rather it wants the address of a string, a `char*`.

Comment: @CoolGuy, I added your point to the TobySpeight's list, is it ok?

Comment: @BumbleBee Sure. Yes, its Ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
char** pWords = calloc(10, sizeof(char*));
```

This is like creating an array of pointers.In this case you are creating array with 10 char pointers.

```
*(pWords + 1) = malloc(10);
```

What you are doing here is allocating space for the second pointer.
*(pWords + 1) takes the address which each pointer points to.

```
strcpy_s(*(pWords + 1), 10, "Test sent\0");
```

Here you copy a string in the allocated space for that pointer.

```
  printf("The string is: %s", *(pWords + 1));
```

And here you just print the contents of the pointer.